# How can I adjust my fa.diagram function to correct the overlapping?

Tags: r, factorial, psych

I want to adjust the function's parameters so that the items don't overlap. I've tried changing the rsize, e.size and gap.size but nothing works. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If this is made for the purpose of presenting this to others, you can save your fa.diagram() as a pdf using the pdf() command in R, specifying the height to be much larger than the width.

Something like:

```
pdf("my_fa_diagram.pdf", height=30, width=5)
fa.diagram(faresults, main="Factor Analysis")
dev.off()
```